# How do I create an extension function in Kotlin, which operates on a class?

Tags: java, mockito, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Imagine, I have this line of code:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito
val mock = Mockito.mock(Sim2ParametersProvider::class.java)
```

I want to be able to write it like this:

```
val mock = Sim2ParametersProvider::class.mock()
```

How do I do this?

I tried

```
fun <T : kotlin.Any> kotlin.reflect.KClass<T>.mock() = Mockito.mock(this)
```

but it gives me compiler errors.

Comment: Not answering your question, but I found the following function to be more useful: `inline fun<reified T : Any> mock() = Mockito.mock(T::class.java)` Usage: `val foo = mock<Foo>()`. In many cases you don't even have to write out the type parameter because of type inference.

Comment: Take a look at this nice project: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're slightly mixing up KClass and java Class.  The following compiles for me, to extend java classes:

```
fun <T> Class<T>.mock() = Mockito.mock(this)
val mock1 = FooClass::class.java.mock()
```

Also the following compiles for me, extending Kotlin KClass:

```
fun <T: Any> KClass<T>.mock() = Mockito.mock(this.java)
val mock2 = FooClass::class.mock()
```

Assuming that FooClass is a class, of course.